# Boost 1.68. installation

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, c++14

I'm installing boost 1.68.0 on my system. I would like to verify that installing with the default system compiler (GCC 4.4.7 in this case) will not affect any boost features leveraging C++14 or greater. My project uses a compiler much newer then GCC 4.4.7 - am I limiting my boost feature set by not installing with the same compiler?

Currently I only use header-only libraries, but I would like to make sure things are ok if I ever start using more.

Comment: Well, this depends on your system and how you perform the install.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using header-only libraries, than your system compiler is irrelevant - only your project compiler is important.

However, if you start using precompiled boost libraries, they **must** be compiled with your project compiler, otherwise, you will potentially (and most likely!) end up with ABI incompatibility, manifesting itself (at best) with linking errors, and at worst with random bugs and crashes in your application.

Comment: Only for static linking though, correct? Dynamic linking should be taken care of at run-time I think...

Comment: @zeus_masta_funk, no, that would be regardless of this. Nothing will be taker care of, just error manifestations might be different.

Comment: I see. More generally, is this primarily an issue for C++ libraries due to name-mangling? For example, I link against many different C system libraries all compiled with the default system compiler - and (so far) have not noticed any issues.

Comment: @zeus_masta_funk, yes, this is a C++ thing. You are usually fine with C libraries.